# Behaviour of Enhanced Domain in API Integration

Tags: api, integration, soap-api, mydomain, enhanced-domains

We have enabled an enhanced domain for one of the Sandbox org. This org is being used by an external system to call the APIs of Salesforce.

After enabling enhanced domains the API integration for https://test.salesforce.com, stopped working with the below error:
The URL <old_URL> has moved to a <new_URL>.

As mentioned in this URL: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000393816&type=1

> Existing API integrations that use the generic
> https://test.salesforce.com URL continue to work when you deploy
> enhanced domains unless the My Domain option, Prevent login from
> https://test.salesforce.com, is enabled.

We have checked our Salesforce sandbox org doesn't have "Prevent login from https://test.salesforce.com" enabled.

**Question:**
**Can someone please confirm, if they have got a similar error after enabling the enhanced domains for the Sandbox org?**

Comment: I believe the login at test.salesforce.com works, but there may be a hard-coded reference to the non-enhanced domain on a subsequent request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error might be that once they are doing a SOAP login or a login via the OAuth 2.0, they are calling your sandbox instance with the old URL.

I would ask them to replace `MyDomainName--SandboxName.InstanceName.my.salesforce.com` to the new URL `MyDomainName--SandboxName.sandbox.my.salesforce.com`

> Notice that instead of the InstanceName now, it is sandbox in the new URL format